# How to retrieve specific information from a list in python?

Tags: python

I have a file from which I would like to retrieve specific information.

First, I extracted the lines of interest and I put them in a list:

```
array = []
file_in = open("Traj.pdb", "r")
  for line in file_in:
      if line.startswith('TITLE'):
          array.append(line)
```

I end up with a list like this:

> ['TITLE     Protein in INSANE! Membrane
>   UpperLeaflet>POPC:POPE:CHOL=31.0:41.0:28.0
>   LowerLeaflet>POPC:POPE:CHOL=31.0:41.0:28.0 t= 1500000.00000\n', 'TITLE
>   Protein in INSANE! Membrane UpperLeaflet>POPC:POPE:CHOL=31.0:41.0:28.0
>   LowerLeaflet>POPC:POPE:CHOL=31.0:41.0:28.0 t= 1500020.00000\n', 'TITLE
>   Protein in INSANE! Membrane UpperLeaflet>POPC:POPE:CHOL=31.0:41.0:28.0
>   LowerLeaflet>POPC:POPE:CHOL=31.0:41.0:28.0 t= 1500040.00000\n']

I would like to extract the "t=" information (t= 1500000.00000, t= 1500020.00000, t= 1500040.00000 ...etc) but I don't know how to do it. As you can see, the elements of my list are sentences and I'm a little bit confused on how I can retrieve the specific information in this case. I would really appreciate your help or advice.

Comment: Seems line you need `array.append(line.strip().split('=')[-1])` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

array_with_elements_i_want = []

for elem in array:
    array_with_elements_i_want.append(re.search(r"t= (.)*", elem).group(0))
```

Or even better:

```
import re

array_with_elements_i_want = []

for elem in array:
    v = re.search(r"t= (.)*", elem)
    if v is not None:
        array_with_elements_i_want.append(v.group(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

split your list on `t=`, it gives you left and right halves. You only need the right half i.e content after `t=`. Also, make sure that you remove the new line character `\n` at the end of the right half.

```
l = ['TITLE Protein in INSANE! Membrane UpperLeaflet>POPC:POPE:CHOL=31.0:41.0:28.0 LowerLeaflet>POPC:POPE:CHOL=31.0:41.0:28.0 t= 1500000.00000\n', 'TITLE Protein in INSANE! Membrane UpperLeaflet>POPC:POPE:CHOL=31.0:41.0:28.0 LowerLeaflet>POPC:POPE:CHOL=31.0:41.0:28.0 t= 1500020.00000\n', 'TITLE Protein in INSANE! Membrane UpperLeaflet>POPC:POPE:CHOL=31.0:41.0:28.0 LowerLeaflet>POPC:POPE:CHOL=31.0:41.0:28.0 t= 1500040.00000\n']
result = []
for line in l:
    splitted_arr = line.split("t= ")
    # Consider only the right half
    splitted_arr = splitted_arr[1]
    # Remove the last character i.e \n
    splitted_arr = splitted_arr[:len(splitted_arr)-1]
    result.append(splitted_arr)
print(result)
```